# Django Query Filter

Tags: python, django, django-views

The following line in my view selects all records that have a delay of 0

t = Times.objects.filter(delay = 0)

How do i write it such that it selects everything but with delay 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try doing?

```
t = Times.objects.exclude(delay=0)
```

I think that will work for you.

Hope that helps,
Joe

Answer (score 2):

With [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `exclude()` method instead of the `filter()` method

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

Answer (score 0):

It's [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters). You want:

`t = Times.objects.filter(delay__ne=0)`